# Cant link moment.js Library

Tags: javascript

i am trying to link the moment.js library with my code , just getting started with javascript and i know the code works because i did it on another pc , now i transferred it to another pc and i changed the script tag yet idk what is the problem , i saved it with UTF - 8

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- reference Moment.js library -->
<script src="C:\Users\Rajarshi\Desktop\Internship\Raj_Intern\Date_Calculator_Project\moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

the code is fine and its just not working here

Comment: How are you serving the HTML file?

Comment: serving ? i didnt get u

Comment: Which browser are you using? I believe the `src` path is the problem here... either you need to add something like `file://localhost/C:/` or change the browser

Comment: using firefox , i tried it with MS Edge and chrome same thing , i have rechecked the location multiple times

Comment: Edit: its working after i added the file://localhost/C:/

Comment: Why not using a relative path (based on the location of your HTML file)?

Comment: the entire thing is in one folder itself both the html file and the moment library thats why

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not working because you dont have that file on your computer. Add this script tag instead.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

It will load MomentJS from CDN. Since you are a begginer you can use it this way until you get more into coding. :)

Comment: thanks a lot for that its working now with the CDN , yet i dont understand why it wont load locally